# How to pass an array to controler from view ??

Tags: laravel-5

Hi guys I have an array that is created in my View side and I want to pass it to a contoller so I can insert it in to my database.. I have seen examples  that use json encode and decoding but how do i apply this to my laravel 5 project ?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your controller code. However, one way for that is to pass them as query parameters.

```
<a href="/my/route?{{implode('&',$myArray)}}">Link</a>
```